# Syncing Two String Lists Using Hash Table

Tags: list, synchronization, hashtable, bloom-filter

If I have two different lists of strings, is it possible using a hash table to sync the two lists using a small fixed amount of data? False positives would be OK, but not false negatives. I was looking at the list of hash data structures on Wiki and the Bloom filter one seems like it might be what I'm looking for, but I've never taken an algorithms course so I was hoping someone could spell out in more simple terms how the hash would work in this case. Any suggestions appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What do you expect the output of the algorithm to be: the union of the lists? The intersection? No output, but just modification of the input lists to make them both the union? The intersection? What would a "false positive" mean in terms of syncing two lists? Does that mean a value that you think is is both lists but is not in one, or even not in both lists?

Comment: No output, each would become the union of the two. False positive in terms of allowing duplicates to be sent (where it's already on both lists), but can't miss any.  I was thinking either a hash table or graph might be able to do this.